# Sending JavaScript Object through AJAX works, JSON doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, rest

I'm trying to send data through AJAX and most places I read online say I need to send it as JSON. However, If I try to send it as JavaScript Object it actually works, wheres if I try to send it as JSON it gives me a CORS error (but that's another topic: here's a link to the issue: [API Gateway CORS: no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header (NON-PROXY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978742/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-non-proxy)).

I guess my question is, is it perfectly fine for me to send the data as JavaScript object as oppose to JSON? is there a benefit of doing one over the other?

Example:

This works: (Sending data as JS Object):

```
$("#xform").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var obj = { xnumber: 1 };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'adddresshere',
                    data: obj,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                }).done(function (result) {
                    table.clear();
                    table.rows.add(result).draw();
                });
            });
```

This doesn't work - (sending data as JSON)

```
$("#xform").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var obj = { xnumber: 1 };
                var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'adddresshere',
                    data: myJSON,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                }).done(function (result) {
                    table.clear();
                    table.rows.add(result).draw();
                });
            });
```

So can I just stick with sending JS object from now on as long as it works (like it does for me right now)?

Comment: jQuery does the `JSON.stringify` for you when you set `data` as an object and `contentType` is `application/json`. See the `contentType` [setting documentation on jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings). You might also be interested in reading further about how it always sends a preflight request if that value is used...

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Thank you so much! so like you said it looks like jQuery does that automatically. Which maybe explains why I get the CORS error by trying to JSON.stringify an already stringified JSON which results in syntax error which results in a response different than code:200 which doesn't have the 'Access-control-allow-origin' header (only code:200) has it - or something along those lines. Anyhow, thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Short Answer is Yes.

Explanation: 
When the online blogs says that you need to pass JSON objects - They mean you need to send Java Script Object Notation objects. When you write it like:

```
var obj = { xnumber: 1 }
```

You are already creating a JSON object. This is good to send via ajax call. When you do a JSON stringify operation, it basically converts the above JSON into string. Hence, the server is unable to treat as JSON object and it will fail.

Comment: But var obj = { xnumber: 1 } is not JSON though. If you JSON.stringify that JS object like this myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj) then it becomes JSON resulting like this: myJSON = { "xnumber": 1}. Here is another example of the difference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_stringify.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). There is JSON, which is a text format for sending data across the wire, and there are objects.

Answer (score -2):

Your JavaScript Object is deserialized JSON. As [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) pointed out, JSON.stringify serializes your JavaScript Object to be sent over the wire.

Comment: Is not JSON. Here is the difference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_stringify